# Can we hook Options Menu in android over a Button click listener?

Tags: android, onclicklistener, android-button

I want to hook this menu on a button click listner, is it possible to do so and is it possible to change the color of the background of options menu? Thanks in anticipation

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
           menu.add(0, 1, Menu.NONE, "First");
            menu.add(0, 2, Menu.NONE, "Second");
            return true;

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using a combination of these two functions.

[`invalidateOptionsMenu()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#invalidateOptionsMenu%28%29) and 
[`onPrepareOptionsMenu()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPrepareOptionsMenu%28android.view.Menu%29)

you should override `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` and in your button click listener call `invalidateOptionsMenu()`.

You can also use [`openOptionsMenu()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#openOptionsMenu%28%29) to programmatically open the options menu.